# Getting a list of values from CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I got a piece of csv file with order list which looks like this:

```
CUSTOMER_CODE,CUSTOMER_NAME,NAME,PRODUCT
1044, C1, Name1, Arduino,
1044, C1, Name1, ESP8266,
1048, C2, Name1, Arduino Uno,
1042, C3, Name1, ESP32,
1049, C4, Name1, Arduino Mega,
1042, C3, Name1, Nexus 4,
```

Now I just want to extract list of customer codes 
`[1042, 1044 ,1048 ,1049]`

not

`[1042, 1044 ,1044,1044,1044,1044,1044,1044,1048,1048,1048,1048,1048,1048,1048,1049 etc.]`

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import MySQLdb, csv
CUSTOMER_CODES = []

with open('Customers.csv','r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)

    for row in reader:
        if len(CUSTOMER_CODES) == 0:
            #adding 1st value
            CUSTOMER_CODES.append(int(row['CUSTOMER_CODE']))
        for i in range(0,len(CUSTOMER_CODES)):
            #check each value of table
            print CUSTOMER_CODES
            if CUSTOMER_CODES[i] == int(row['CUSTOMER_CODE']):
                print "Code is already here "+ str(row['CUSTOMER_CODE'])
            else:
                CUSTOMER_CODES.append(int(row['CUSTOMER_CODE']))
```

And instead having output like this:

```
[1044, 1045, 1047....]
```

I have this:

```
[1044, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1047, 1047, 1047, 1047, 1047, 1047, 1047, 1047, 1047,
```

Answer (score 5):

Simply use a `set` instead of a `list`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import MySQLdb, csv
CUSTOMER_CODES = set()

with open('Customers.csv','r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)

    for row in reader:
        CUSTOMER_CODES.add(int(row['CUSTOMER_CODE']))
```

Or using set comprehension (assuming Python 2.6+):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import MySQLdb, csv

with open('Customers.csv','r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    CUSTOMER_CODES = {int(row['CUSTOMER_CODE']) for row in reader}
```

If you'd like a sorted list, add `CUSTOMER_CODES = sorted(CUSTOMER_CODES)`.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org):

```
# Import your csv file into Dataframe
df = pd.read_csv('yourfile.csv')

# Extract the column you want and export to list
a = df['CUSTOMER_CODE'].tolist()

# Sort it
a = a.sort()
```

This returns:

```
In [29]: a
Out[29]: [1042, 1042, 1044, 1044, 1048, 1049]
```

EDIT: to remove duplicates you can:

```
a = df['CUSTOMER_CODE'].drop_duplicates().tolist()
```

and then sort.

Comment: This does not remove doubles.